# order table by optional value in second table (mysql, wordpress)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join, group-by

I want to order all rows of a table ("posts") by a (sort-)value ("sortDate") that is stored in a second table ("meta").
The (sort-)value of the second table is stored as a key-value pair. the key is 'publishDate'
The linking column between both tables is "postID".
The (sort-)value of the second table is optional, or can be entered multiple times.
-> If the (sort-)value is entered multiple times, i want to use the maximum.
-> If the (sort-)value is not present in the second table, i want to use the "postDate" - value of the first table instead.

This is my solution:

```
SELECT posts.postID,posts.postDate,metaDate.publishDate,
  CASE
    WHEN metaDate.publishDate is null Then posts.postDate
    ELSE metaDate.publishDate
  END AS sortDate /*fallback for those rows that do not have a matching key-value pair in second table*/
From posts
Left Join
  (
  Select meta.postID,MAX(metaValue) as publishDate
  From meta
  Where meta.metaKey = 'publishDate'
  GROUP BY meta.postID
  ) As metaDate /*create a table with the maximum of publishDate, therefor handle multiple entries*/
ON posts.postID = metaDate.postID
ORDER BY sortDate DESC;
```

see also
[sqlfiddle with this solution --->](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef15a/10%20%22sqlfiddle.com%20with%20my%20solution)

Is there a smarte / faster way to do so?
As i am not a sql expert - anything i have overseen ?

(Background:
the structure of the tables is a wordpress-database-structure, therefore it is given, a related topic would be "sort posts by custom fields in wordpress" - but the solutions i found did not handle multiple or optional custom fields)

Thanks for comments and support

Comment: This is a reasonable solution.

Comment: a colloque told me:

Try to avoid “case … when…”. Not wrong but slow. Check “coalesce” function.

Probably something like (untested):
SELECT posts.postID,posts.postDate,metaDate.publishDate, coalesce(metaDate.publishDate ,posts.postDate) AS sortDate

Comment: Your colleague is incorrect.  The `case` statement and `coalesce()` should have very similar functionality.